# Is it possible to inject objects into templates in a transversal way?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have multiple templates, but in all I need to know if the user is authenticated or not to know whether to show the access button or exit.

Currently in each controller I must send the object of the user entity to the data model for the template, but this means initializing the user service on all controllers.

Is there any way to intercept the controller and automatically inject the user entity into the model without affecting the normal use of the model in each controller?

I currently know that it is possible to use the aspect interceptor to control the use of controllers from their classes and their functions, but I don't know how to intercept the "model" argument and fill it with the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `@ControllerAdvice` with `@ModelAttribute`. Just create a class like this:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ModelAttributesForEveryController {

    private UserService userService;


    @Autowired
    public ModelAttributesForEveryController(UserService userService) {
        this. userService = userService;
    }


    @ModelAttribute("userEntity")
    public String userEntity() {
        // Here goes your logic to get the User entity
        return theUserEntity;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("isLoggedIn")
    public String isLoggedIn() {
        // Here goes your logic to determine if logged in or not
        return isLogged;
    }
```

And then you can use that `model attribute` named **userEntity** in you template like any other attribute

For example using the **isLoggedIn** model attribute (a very dummy example):

```html
<button th:if="${isLoggedIn}"> Exit</button>
<button th:if="${!isLoggedIn}"> Sign In</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know the authenticated state, you can add the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` dependency to your project, then you can use `sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()"` to check logged in or not.

Comment: I do not use spring security for authentication.